# Assign value to a variable upon error

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

What I am trying to do is that certain value gets reset if there has been an error. Something like:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim feeder As String
Dim origen As String

On Error GoTo errhandler:
For j=1 to 100
   r = Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (C:C=""" & feeder & """) * (D:D=""" & origen & """),0)")
Next j

Exit Sub

errhandler:
r = 0
End Sub
```

But how do I force it to go back to the `For` if there is an error?

Comment: first declare r as a variant in the loop.  Then use `isError(r)` to determine if you do anything or not.

Comment: Why does it have to be declared in the loop?

Comment: because once it gets set to an integer it will not longer accept an error.  so we need to re dimension the variable each time.

Comment: So I still ned to declare it outside the loop and then `ReDim` it inside at the beginning of it.

Comment: No remove the first and add `Dim r as variant` inside loop.

Comment: I didn't know that, so if I declare a variant variable and then assign some value to it, it will not accept any type of value other than the first one?

Comment: That is why it is important to declare variables.

Comment: I may be wrong, but It works when I do it that way.  But @EoinS just gave a great alternative.

Comment: One last recommendation you should dictate the sheet on which the formula is to be run. `Sheets("Sheet1").Evaluate(...` or it will try to evaluate on the active sheet, this may be what you want but it is more robust to declare the sheet, just in case.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, I just didn't want to add unnecessary code to the question. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ErrHanlding you could use IsError to set the value of `r` on Error:

```
Sub t1()
  Dim feeder As String
  Dim origen As String
  For j = 1 To 100
   Dim r As Variant
   If IsError(Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (C:C=""" & feeder & """) * (D:D=""" & origen & """),0)")) Then
    r = 0
   Else
    r = Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (C:C=""" & feeder & """) * (D:D=""" & origen & """),0)")
   End If
  Debug.Print r ' Just for you to check
 Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Is " On Error Resume Next" actually needed?

Comment: @user3598756 no, the Iserror traps the error and so it will never try to put an error in r.

Comment: @ScottCraner That's what I supposed, hence my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Resume Next` statement

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim feeder As String
Dim origen As String

On Error GoTo errhandler:
For j=1 to 100
   r = Evaluate("=MATCH(1, (C:C=""" & feeder & """) * (D:D=""" & origen & """),0)")
Next j

Exit Sub

errhandler:
r = 0
resume Next

End Sub
```